# How to test for "earlier the better" type of effect in data

Tags: hypothesis-testing

My data consists of people rating 50 different pictures and I'd like to test whether earlier pictures shown to people have higher scores. I can view this graphically (they do seem to have higher scores) but I'm wondering a simple way to conduct a hypothesis test for this. Can anyone suggest an approach?

Comment: Create 2 samples, one with early ratings and the other one with later rating and do a simple t-test to evaluate whether the difference between the 2 sample is statistically significant ?

Comment: Can you describe the experiment in more detail? For example: Are these the same 50 pictures? Are they shown in the same or random order? Do you want to adjust for "picture" effects even though the hypothesis is about the viewing order?

Answer (score 0):

We really need some more details (as requested in the comments by @dipetkov), so please provide those.

But, you could use some form of regression model, where score is regressed on a variable representing the time order, and possibly other variables.

But how to use such a model, and which inferences you can draw, would depend on information you have not yet provided.